# 1D Integral always evaluates to 0 and Replace All

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am a bit puzzled by Mathematica's behaviour. I am trying to evaluate some 1D integrals which depend on parameters `phi1,phi2` numerically (functions `f1` and `f2`), however `NIntegrate` always outputs 0 whereas plotting the integrand with `Plot` shows that the integral is non-zero.

Here is the code in question:

```
t = 1;
lambda = 0.3;
hbarOmega = 4;
q = 0.5;
alpha = 4 lambda^2 t (Sin[q/2])/q;

A[k_] := 2 t (Sin[q/2]/q) Sin[k] (1/(hbarOmega + 4 t Sin[q/2] Sin[k]) + 
 1/(hbarOmega - 4 t Sin[q/2] Sin[k]));

B[k_] := 2 t (Sin[q/2]/q) Sin[k] (1/(hbarOmega + 4 t Sin[q/2] Sin[k]) - 
 1/(hbarOmega - 4 t Sin[q/2] Sin[k]));

e1[k_] := 4 t lambda^2  (Sin[q/2]/q) B[k + q/2] Sin[k + q/2];
e2[k_] := -4 t lambda^2  (Sin[q/2]/q) B[k - q/2] Sin[k - q/2];
en[k_] := -2 t Cos[k] + e1[k - q] + e2[k + q];
F[k_, phi1_, phi2_] := - alpha (A[k] phi1 + Sin[k] phi2);
mu[phi1_, phi2_] := - 2 alpha Re[phi1 Conjugate[phi2]];

hMf[k_, phi1_, phi2_] := {{en[k + q/2],F[k, phi1, phi2]}, {Conjugate[F[k, phi1, phi2]], en[k - 
q/2]}};


u[k_, phi1_, phi2_] := Transpose[Eigenvectors[hMf[k, phi1, phi2]]];
enMf[k_, phi1_, phi2_] := ConjugateTranspose[u[k, phi1, phi2]].hMf[k, phi1, phi2].u[k, phi1, 
phi2];

o[k_, phi1_, phi2_] := ConjugateTranspose[u[k, phi1, phi2]].{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}.u[k, phi1,phi2];


f1[phi1_?NumericQ,phi2_?NumericQ] := (1/(2 Pi)) NIntegrate[
Sin[k]*(o[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] Boole[
     enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]] + 
   o[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] Boole[
     enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]]), {k, -Pi, Pi}];

f2[phi1_?NumericQ,phi2_?NumericQ] := (1/(2 Pi)) NIntegrate[A[k] (o[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] 
Boole[enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]] + 
   o[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] Boole[
     enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]]), {k, -Pi,Pi}];

f1[1, 1]

Plot[Sin[k]*(o[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] Boole[
   enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]] + 
 o[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] Boole[
   enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]]) /. {phi1 -> 1, phi2 -> 1}, {k, -Pi, Pi}]

Plot[Sin[k]*(o[k, 1, 1][[1, 1]] Boole[enMf[k, 1, 1][[1, 1]] <= mu[1, 1]] + o[k, 1, 1][[2, 2]] 
Boole[enMf[k, 1, 1][[2, 2]] <= mu[1, 1]]), {k, -Pi, Pi}]
```

So for example, when I evaluate the integral given by `f1[1,1]`, I get an output of 0 alongside with a warning that Mathematica couldn't find all eigenvectors of a 2x2 matrix which is bizarre, because when I plot the eigenvalues separately with:

```
Plot[{enMf[k, 1, 1][[1, 1]], enMf[k, 1, 1][[2, 2]]}, {k, -Pi, Pi}]
```

the warning is not present.

However when I plot the integrand inside `f1` with the same parameters `phi1=1,phi2=1` with:

```
Plot[Sin[k]*(o[k, 1, 1][[1, 1]] Boole[
  enMf[k, 1, 1][[1, 1]] <= mu[1, 1]] + 
o[k, 1, 1][[2, 2]] Boole[
  enMf[k, 1, 1][[2, 2]] <= mu[1, 1]]), {k, -Pi, Pi}]
```

it shows that the integrand is always positive and that the integral should be non-zero.

Moreover, there is another oddity: replacing the parameters `phi1`,`phi2` within the integrand with `/.` for the same values `phi1=1,phi2=1` like so:

```
Plot[Sin[k]*(o[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] Boole[
   enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[1, 1]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]] + 
 o[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] Boole[
   enMf[k, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] <= mu[phi1, phi2]]) /. {phi1 -> 1,phi2 -> 1}, {k, -Pi, Pi}]
```

gives a different plot compared to just substituting the values `phi1=1,phi2=1` directly:

```
Plot[Sin[k]*(o[k, 1, 1][[1, 1]] Boole[
  enMf[k, 1, 1][[1, 1]] <= mu[1, 1]] + 
o[k, 1, 1][[2, 2]] Boole[
  enMf[k, 1, 1][[2, 2]] <= mu[1, 1]]), {k, -Pi, Pi}]
```

which I find very bizarre and assume has to do with delayed evaluation. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that it's a delayed evaluation problem! I traced the problem back to `Eigenvectors`. Note that it behaves differently when given symbolic arguments and numeric ones:

```
Eigenvectors[hMf[0.01, phi1, phi2]] /. {phi1 -> 1, phi2 -> 1}

(* Out: {{-4.064089631, 1.}, {0.2460575654, 1.}} *)

Eigenvectors[hMf[0.01, 1, 1]]

(* Out: {{0.2389308952, 0.9710365736}, {-0.9710365736, 0.2389308952}} *)
```

The deal is that Mathematica both 1) doesn't normalize eigenvectors when symbolic and 2) might order them differently. Note that

```
Normalize /@ (Eigenvectors[hMf[0.01, phi1, phi2]] /. {phi1 -> 1, phi2 -> 1})

(* Out: {{-0.9710365736, 0.2389308952}, {0.2389308952, 0.9710365736}} *)
```

Which is the same as `Eigenvectors[hMf[0.01, 1, 1]]`, but in reverse order.

```
Sort[Normalize /@ (Eigenvectors[hMf[0.01, phi1, phi2]] /. {phi1 -> 1, phi2 -> 1})]
  == Sort[Eigenvectors[hMf[0.01, 1, 1]]]

(* Out: True *)
```

So, you'll need to decide whether the vectors should be normalized, and whether the order matters!

But there's also another issue: different normalizations can be chosen. Normalized eigenvectors are unique only up to norm 1 elements of your field, which in this case are $\pm 1$ if we're doing this over the reals. Which normalization do you want? For this reason, even after redefining `u[k_, phi1_, phi2_] := Transpose[Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[hMf[k, phi1, phi2]]];`, we still have

```
o[0.01, phi1, phi2][[2, 2]] /. {phi1 -> 1, phi2 -> 1}

(* Out: 0.2320106378 *)

o[0.01, 1, 1][[2, 2]] 
(* Out: -0.2320106378 *)
```

So that's another choice to make as well.

---

However, there is a way to avoid some of this, since I noticed you seem to be using the matrix of eigenvectors for diagonalization.
Check out `JordanDecomposition` and other `*Decomposition` functions, which return not only the decomposition, but similarity matrices you can use as well! Also look at `Eigensystem`, which returns a list `{evalues, evectors}` for which `M.Transpose[evectors] == Transpose[evectors].DiagonalMatrix[evalues]`. You could use this to save on some computation in calculating `enMf` by simply using `DiagonalMatrix[evalues]`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Concerning your remark on normalization (last bit of code in your answer), I think that its the ordering of the vectors that's causing the sign change, as the structure of the matrix $o$ ( $o = u^{\dagger} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} u $) implies that its diagonal elements are invariant under the change in sign of any of the eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ making up $u = (v_1,v_2)$. Also, now I understand why the plots of the integrand are different but I am still not sure why the integral f[1,1] is zero since a plot of the integrand suggests otherwise.

Comment: Update: so making all the functions from hMf down numerical with ?NumericQ gives a non-zero integral, however now I get error messages like so: "Part specification o[k,2,2][[1,1]] is longer than depth of object" which I guess arise from Part being evaluated prematurely. I am a bit confused by this message because since we are using NIntegrate, shouldnt k always have a numerical value?

Comment: @RuslanMushkaev Try `Indexed[o[k.2.2], {1, 1}]` instead of `Part`.  `NIntegrate` inspects the integrand symbolically to determine which method to choose.  Good thing you didn’t have `o[k, 2, 2][[1]]`, because that evaluates to `k`, which would give you strange results and no error.